# NSB V7 service attempting to subscribe to V2.5 service

Tags: messaging, nservicebus

I have a situation where my NSB v7.2 service needs to subscribe to a NSB v2.5 i.e. very old service.

In the NSB v2.5 app I get an error complaining that the message body is empty. It seems V7.2 subscribe info in NSB v7.2 messages is all in the headers.

I am able to manually subscribe my service, which works ok. However in a PROD environment this is not ideal as if services are moved around it won't tolerate this.

The ultimate solution is of course an upgrade of my old service. This is not possible immediately as it would require upgrading all subscribers as we'd moving to the Outbox pattern and the subscribing services are of various NSB flavours not all guaranteed to handle messages idempotently.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the same guidelines as for subscribing to web services, in that you create an NSB service that only exists to receive the v7 subscription requests. It has it's own queue, but shares the same subscription storage as the existing publisher.